# Mod Rewrite condition

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Evening,

Can someone help me with the following condition?

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?\.|)(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.(co\.uk|com)$ [NC]
```

I want to match all subdomains and no-subdomains, a few domains and a few tlds in my rule. The above rule doesn't work though.

Can someone help? Thanks.

**Update**

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?\.)?(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.(co\.uk|com)$ [NC]
```

Works. I need a further exception for domain1.co.uk as that is my primary domain. I'm stuck in an infinite loop. Note I still need to rewrite from domain1.com though.

Comment: Does altering the beginning to `^(.*?\.)?` work? (Untested here..)

Comment: @Wrikken thanks. See edit. I'm stuck in an infinite loop now :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many `RewriteCond`'s as you like....

```
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*?\.)?(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.(co\.uk|com)$
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain1\.co\.uk$
```

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to squeeze it all into one regex. This is more readable.

Comment: One regex would probably be `^(.*?\.)?(domain1(?!\.com)|domain2|domain3)\.(co\.uk|com)$`, but legibility indeed suffers.